# Force Boolean format to TRUE/FALSE in Enterprise Architect XML output

Tags: xml, enterprise-architect

I have the problem, that enterprise architect (Version 9.0) use 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE, when I trigger the XML (V. 1.1) export function. But I need (to support a third party software) the TRUE/FALSE format in the XML file.
My EA project uses a MySQL database and the boolean values are saved as 1/0 there. I don´t have that behavior on a local .eap file.

Is there any way to force the format to TRUE/FALSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked to the support and there is no solution for that specific problem.

Only the XMI V. 2 based formats ensure a more consistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different behavior in on a project in MySQL as opposed to a .eap file then you should report it as a bug to Sparx Systems. Regardless of the repository type, the resulting XMI file should always be the same.

You can use this [webform](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/bug_report.html) to fill in the details.

Before you do that it might be worth to try if you have the same problem in v12.
If it is already solved in v12 then there's no point in reporting it.

Comment: The values of the affected attributes are stored as TRUE/FALSE in the .eap file (which is a MS Access database). In the MySQL database they are stored as 1/0, so I think that the EA is configured to do that formatting.

Comment: That is fine, but the resulting xmi file should be the same, regardless of TRUE/FALSE or 0/1 in the database. If not then it is a bug.

Comment: I installed the v12. and the problem is still there. I will report it as a bug.